# Proof about finite fields and primitive elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, information-theory

Let $a$ be a nonzero element of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then $a = \omega^i$ for some primitive element $\omega$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. This means that the equation $x^n=a$ has a solution in $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $gcd(n, q-1)|i.$ I am asked to prove this fact. I have no idea how to start at all. I can start off with the forward implication by setting $x^n = \omega^i$ but I do not know how to proceed at all. I can use the logic that since $\omega$ is a generator, the order of $\omega = q- 1$ but I am not sure what to do. Can anyone please help me get started off? I missed my class.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not sure I follow... How does that relate to gcd(n,q−1)|i

Comment: Sorry, I read a bit carelessly. Anyway, if you have covered the subgroups of cyclic groups, then this follows from there. The $n$th powers form a subgroup of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$, generated by $\omega^n$. From the theory of cyclic groups you can deduce that $\omega^n$ and $\omega^{\gcd(n,q-1)}$ generate the same subgroup etc.